# Superfish Menu disappearing in IE9

Tags: css, wordpress, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, superfish

The website I'm working on is [www.shandon.com.au](http://www.shandon.com.au) . 
It looks pretty well on every browser except IE9, where the navigation menu disappears (it uses Superfish JS).

I'm running a Mac so I can test it only on IETester in VMWare, and if I don't move the mouse everything looks fine, whenever I hover the webiste window, it disappears and the search box move down.

What should fix this? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just as a starter point, I'd have a look at what CSS you have set for only `.ie` / `.ie9` elements. When I remove these classes from the `<html>` tag then the menu stops disappearing

Comment: did my solution not work for you? (I saw the un-acceptance) can you implement the changes and put it online so I can have a look?

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to update this. It turned out that the <ul> element before the search box HAD TO STAY THERE, in order to get the correct layout. I'm still wondering why, without that <ul> everything is messed up :

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

That's one of the problems, change this to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
```

Then delete this line from the head:

```
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie ie9 no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> <![endif]-->
```

I don't think you need IE9 specific detection, it will render everything correctly in your website anyway.